# After reinstalling a package, the cproj file was changed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I issued the following command in the nuget console:

```
update-package mvcreportviewer -reinstall -ProjectName Myproject
```

and for some reason it added the following in my cproj file:

> ```
> <Reference Include="MvcReportViewer, Version=0.3.5167.24909, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
>   <HintPath>..\..\..\Build Files\packages\MvcReportViewer.0.3.1\lib\net40\MvcReportViewer.dll</HintPath>
>   <Private>True</Private>
> </Reference>
> ```

**What is the purpose of this? Why is it not enough to simply have the version number in packages.config?**

Comment: because the packages.config is not used by the compiler and the csproj file is?

Comment: @rene how do we ensure that the packages.config is used?

Comment: rewrite the C# compiler? Not sure if [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) can do that for you.

Comment: so will nuget add to the cproj file EVERY TIME there is a package restore/update/reinstall by nuget?

Comment: Yes, it will. otherwise your project might not compile.

Comment: so what does <Private>True</Private> do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129653/discussion-between-meggie-luski-and-rene).

Comment: `<Private>True</Private>` is the "Copy to output directory" option when you are looking at the reference's properites in your project in visual studio. `True` means do the copy, `False` means do not copy. The "Private" stands for "Is this a private assembly that is not expected to be present and registered in the GAC on the target computer this program will run on". So if a assembly is not private the program assumes it can just refrence the DLL without it being there in the diretory and `Assembly.Resolve` will find it.

Comment: I agree with rene and Scott Chamberlain. When we install NuGet packages on our project, it will add references and content files into our project. So your project need to recognize these content based on the settings from .csproj file when compile. I suggest you quote rene and Scott Chamberlain's comments as answer and mark them. It is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.